# CSS & HTML Button Under each other instead of Side By Side

Tags: html, css

Basically the issue I am having today is the buttons I'm making are appearing under each other rather than side by side.

This is my code CSS:

(Buttons are 140 x 32)

```
/* BUTTON */

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#redbutton li.newbutton {
    background: url("../images/blank_button.png") no-repeat;
    width: 140px;


    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-decoration: none;   
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;   
    line-height:30px;   
}
ul#redbutton li.newbutton:hover {
    background: url("../images/blank_button_hover.png") no-repeat;
    width: 140px;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-decoration: none;   
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;   
    line-height:30px;   
}
/* BUTTON END*/
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="redbutton">
<a href="link.php"><li class="newbutton">TEXT</li></a>
<a href="link.php"><li class="newbutton">TEXT</li></a>
</ul>
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzYLj.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arbel stated, you cannot have anything as a direct child of a `ul` other than an `li`.

In order to get the buttons side by side you could use `floats` or you could use `display:inline-block;` like so:

```
ul#redbutton li.newbutton {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hR5mt/

Answer (score 4):

First, fix your HTML (`a` tag can't be a direct child of `ul`)

```
<ul id="redbutton">
    <li class="newbutton"><a href="link.php">TEXT</a></li>
    <li class="newbutton"><a href="link.php">TEXT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then, there are many ways to make the `li`s (which you make look like buttons) appear side by side, this is one of them. Add this to your CSS:

```css
ul#redbutton li.newbutton {
    float:left;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Qh8h2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
ul#redbutton li{
  display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your buttons be displayed side by side you should add `display:inline;` to ul#redbutton li.newbutton css class like

```
ul#redbutton li.newbutton {
  background: url("../images/blank_button.png") no-repeat;
  width: 140px;
  display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, This might work and all, but all you have to do is this.

```html
<button>Your Text</button><br>
    <button>Your Text</button>
```

Comment: This was from 3 years ago my dude 